# Echo a multi line environment variable to a text file using Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, escaping, echo, gitlab-ci

I have an environment variable `%SSH_PRIVATE_KEY%` and would like to print this to a file using the command line, without using a batch file. This is because I need to use this file in a Gitlab-Ci .yml script.

**In Linux, this is as simple as:**

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And this generates:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
DHHDpgIFFFFAQEA4s5JARKOiF/dfherreh/qeGLNaryra7rt927okJmonpJHyCbA5SRyjsST/oC
tJx+YJ0BaNbbHtpbjbMeWgqKPXNAIRng30TXCOLLKverteygerg/ererg/GVFfd5T1v/qY2rGCN
v9yHSw89upy8pA+HvAFFFFHDb2YUAgpyYMqCcZ3vGY0/NDBxQQwDKwrefqwef/wefweqe/wwALb
```

And so on.

**However in Windows, if I try:**

```
echo "%SSH_PRIVATE_KEY%" >  C:\runner\builds\66092d15\0\myproject\.ssh\id_rsa
```

It generates this output:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Because as soon as it reaches the newline character in `%SSH_PRIVATE_KEY%` it escapes the echo command.

How can I print the full `%SSH_PRIVATE_KEY%` to a file using the windows command line?

Comment: How are you assigning a multi-line value to the variable?

Comment: @Magoo It is set as a gitlab secret variable that is added to the pipeline environment. This is explained [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#secret-variables).

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the lines use `echo !VARIABLENAME!`

```
echo !SSH_PRIVATE_KEY! >  C:\runner\builds\66092d15\0\myproject\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Comment: This answer is in fact correct. See my longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Blue7 is right, but as he/she was down voted, here comes the long answer for anyone who did not read that this is gitlab-ci realted:

For ! to work DelayedExpansion must be enabled, and it seems to only work in batch-files. In gitlab this is the case by default. By default cmd will first expand the environment variable and then interpret it. Thus when you write `echo "%SSH_PRIVATE_KEY%"` cmd actually sees

```
echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
DHHDpgIFFFFAQEA4s5JARKOiF/dfherreh/qeGLNaryra7rt927okJmonpJHyCbA5SRyjsST/oC
...
```

Yes, including the `"`! To avoid this, you need to enable late expansion `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. With delayed expansion the environment variables are extended right before passing them to the application. Thus there is also no need for using `"`. Searching for `EnableDelayedExpansion` will provide you with lots of additional information.